# Word style context menu in WPF?

Tags: wpf, ms-word, tooltip, contextmenu

What controls would be most suitable for creating a complex context menu, similar what you see in Windows Word. Should it be pop up, tooltip, or context menu or a transparent window?

What you think would be the best control to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with a ContextMenu, since that is the behaviour you want. Unlike a ToolTip that won't automatically disappear after a few seconds, and it is already set up to by a collection of MenuItems.

Comment: But from the other side it is supposed to contain contextMenu items, not arbitrary controls. Will it work properly if I you put other controls inside? And what will make it disappear?

Comment: As with any WPF container you can put anything you like in there - it doesn't have to be contextMenu items.